# (Year: 2018) Named Anchor when clicked hides other content

Tags: html

This is stupid simple but I don't know why the page is doing what it's doing...

I have a hyperlink `<a href="#OrientationSchedule">See schedule below</a>` and further down on the same page is the named anchor, . When the `See schedule below` is clicked, the page will navigate to the anchor but you can't scroll back up, the content that was there is no longer visible. If you click back, nothing really happens. I've tried this is FF/Chome/IE/Edge, they all behave the same. I don't know if the IIS server is pushing out some specialized headers or something causing... just banging my head is all I know...

URL: http://humanetomorrow.com/help/volunteer.html

I do know the Server is running IIS (don't know the version) and this is a static HTML site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#main` section has overflow set to 'hidden' and when you click on an anchor, content scrolls up in such a way as if parts of the page disappear. It looks like a visual trick.

To solve it, set `#main`'s CSS property `overflow:auto`.

Comment: This does fix the anchor, but the content on the rightside is pushed further down the page. I also see scrollbars so I'm wondering if that's why it was set as hidden. But the CSS is clearly the right direction and not some doc mode or server header being pushed so that is a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot think of an obvious easy fix that would fit SO answer format, otherwise I would have added it. You have to scroll somewhere, that's for sure. It is more of an overall web design question - could be a scroller next to the text, could be another anchor at the bottom, parallax scrolling etc.

Comment: I understand, thank you so much. I'll mark the answer as correct since it does resolve the original question. Again, thank you!